# WCF Generated Proxy Crashes Monodroid and Monotouch

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I've generated a proxy client for my WCF RIA service class via slsvcutil.exe as described in the Xamarin "Introduction to Web Services" document, however when I try to make a call to one of the async methods, my "completed" event handler never gets called -- after a couple of minutes, the app simply terminates from the Android emulator (it does the same thing in Monotouch as well).

After several days of troubleshooting, I finally found the source of the crash, but have no idea how to fix it. I suspect it's a bug in Mono somewhere, but don't know how to troubleshoot any further.

My generated proxy has a class defined like so:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "ChangeSetEntry", Namespace = "DomainServices")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(SL5Proxy.ChangeSetEntry[]))]
public partial class ChangeSetEntry : object
{
...
}
```

(The code above is greatly simplified - there are about a dozen `KnownTypeAttribute()` lines, but I've determined that the one shown above is the source of the problem. It's important to note that the `ChangeSetEntry` object does not have any reference to a `ChangeSetEntry[]` array.)

I found that if I simply comment out the

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(SL5Proxy.ChangeSetEntry[]))]
```

line from the proxy code, everything works 100% correct and my async "completed" handler is called exactly as expected. I don't know why slsvcutil.exe generates the problematic KnownTypeAttribute() line, but it does.

My guess is that there's some kind of infinite recursion that gets created when the `ChangeSetEntry` class tells the runtime serializer that `ChangeSetEntry[]` is a known type -- the runtime tries to resolve the known type, comes back to `ChangeSetEntry` and does it all again.

So I'm curious if anyone else has seen this issue, whether it's a known problem and whether there is a workaround -- perhaps some way to suppress the generation of the `KnownTypeAttribute()` lines from slsvcutil.exe

Comment: I've heard about [KnownType] or [XmlInclude] (they do similar things), not working in MonoTouch.  Not all features in WCF are fully implemented (it is a very large framework).  I think you took the right path by using your workaround, but you might look into changing the service side to remove it there as well.